# Perl replace multiple strings simultaneously (case insensitive)

Tags: perl

Consider the following perl code which works perfectly:

```
%replacements = ("what" => "its", "lovely" => "bad");
($val = $sentence) =~ s/(@{[join "|", keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/g;
```

stackoverflow user sresevoir brilliantly came up with that replacement code that involved using a hash, allowing you to find and replace multiple terms without iterating through a loop.

I've been throwing other various search and replace terms at it programmatically and I've started using it to highlight words that are the result of a search.

The problem (refer to problem code shown below):

Make it case insensitive by adding an "i" before the "g" at the end.
If the search term $thisterm and the search term word contained in $sentence has no difference in case, there are no problems. If the search term $thisterm (i.e. Stackoverflow) and the search term word contained in $sentence is a different case (i.e. stackoverflow), then the result returned is nothing for that term. It's as if I told it to

```
$sentence =~ s/$thisterm//g;
```

Here's the problem code:

```
foreach $thisterm (@searchtermarray) {

# The variable $thisterm has already gone through a filter to remove special characters.

$thistermtochange = $thisterm;

$replacements{$thistermtochange} = "<span style=\"background-color:#FFFFCC;\">$thistermtochange<\/span>";

}

$sentence =~ s/(@{[join "|", keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/ig;
```

I also went back and duplicated the problem with the above original code. It seems the combination of adding the i modifier, using a hash reference, and different case is something Perl doesn't like.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

DB

P. S. I've benefited from stackoverflow for years; but I just signed up for this question and the site wouldn't let me directly comment to sresevoir. As a "brand new" user I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Your code looks very much as though you don't have either `use strict` or `use warnings` at the start. If you have been reading Stack Overflow for a while then you must have come across admonishments to *always* add these pragma to *every* Perl script you write.

Comment: In general it's very much recommended trying to understand the code you use from others: The capture group (now matching case-insensitive) is used to query the `%replacements` hash using that match as key. In most cases such key isn't present however, so Perl substitutes the empty string. That should explain the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep all the keys of the hash in lower case, and do this:

```
s/(@{[join "|", keys %replacements]})/$replacements{ lc $1 }/ig
```

(note the addition of lc)

There are a few other things you ought to consider.

First, as is, if you are trying to replace both `lovely` and `love` with different replacements, `lovely` may or may not ever be found, depending on which key is returned by `keys` first.  To prevent this, it's a good idea to sort by descending length:

```
s/(@{[join "|", sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/ig
```

Second, this technique only works with fixed strings; if your keys contain any regex metacharacters, for instance replacing `how?` with `why?`, it will fail, because `$1` will never be `how?`.  To allow metacharacters (interpreted as literal characters), quote them:

```
s/(@{[join "|", map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/ig
```

From your comment, it seems to me that you want to find certain strings, all in one pass, and add stuff around them (that doesn't vary by which string).  If so, you are going about it the hard way and shouldn't be using a hash at all.  Have an array of the strings you want to search for and replace them:

```
 s/(@{[join "|", map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } @search_strings]})/<span style="background-color:#FFFFCC;">$1<\/span>/ig;
```

Comment: Hi @ysth, I can't change the case. It's purpose is to highlight words that have been searched irregardless of case. Say you have a webpage with the phrase, "World Series Wins". Somebody searches on "series". I need to highlight their search term without changing it to "World series Wins".

Comment: @ysth: What he means is that the *search* should be case-independent, but the replacement string should include whatever was in the original document, not the lower-cased version. In truth the hash method is the wrong solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, if you have a hash like this

```
my %replacements = (
    word => '<span style="background-color:#FFFFCC;">word</span>'
)
```

then the substitution will look like

```
s/(word)/$replacements{$1}/ig;
```

But a case-independent regex pattern will match `WORD` as well, so the replacement expression `$replacements{$1}` will be `$replacements{'WORD'}` which doesn't exist.

While you may be pleased with his solution, `sresevoir` uses an ugly way of embedding a string expression within a regex. This

```
($val = $sentence) =~ s/(@{[join "|", keys %replacements]})/$replacements{$1}/g;
```

would be much better as

```
my $pattern = join '|', keys %replacements;
($val = $sentence) =~ s/($pattern)/$replacements{$1}/g;
```

But you have generalised this hash idea too far and it is the wrong way to make the changes that you need. If your replacement string is a simple function of the original string, as in this case, then it is best written directly as a replacement string using captures from the pattern. I would write it like this

```
my $pattern = join '|', @searchtermarray;
$sentence =~ s{($pattern)}{<span style="background-color:#FFFFCC;">$1</span>\n}ig;
```

But note that that, as it stands, the search will find any words that are *substrings* of anything in the text, and will also go awry if `@searchtermarray` has any strings that contain regex metacharacters. You don't say anything about your actual data so I can't really help you to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin I have a purely academic curiosity to know why the i modifier caused trouble in sresevoir's code, but your code has no such issues.

Comment: it caused trouble because you would look for a key of "Lovely" (or whatever was found) and it wouldn't find the key of "lovely", causing the hash to return undef (which then is treated as an empty string with a warning - you do have warnings enabled, right?)

Comment: @user4339353: I've added to the beginning of my solution to explain what goes wrong when you just add the `/i` modifier.